# Pandas insert row every given time interval

Tags: python, pandas

Having the following DF:

```
    id           init_time          event_time  value
0    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 00:21:30      1
1    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 00:21:35      3
2    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 00:23:25      7
3    1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 15:21:30      3
4    1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 15:22:25      6
5    1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 16:21:25      9
6    1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 18:21:25     10
7    1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 18:30:25     10
8    2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 08:21:25      1
9    2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 09:11:20      2
10   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 09:21:25      3
11   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 10:12:12      4
12   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 10:30:00      5
13   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 11:50:48      6
14   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 11:59:15      7
```

I would like to group by `id`, then based on the ***init_time*** insert a row every X interval and repeat Y times. Notice that `init_time` is the same for all rows and `event_time` is the time when the row was created.

---

For example if `X` is `1h` and `Y` is `5` times, the result DF would be:

```
    id           init_time          event_time  value
0    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 00:21:25     -- ⎫
1    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 00:21:30      1 ⎪
2    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 00:21:35      3 ⎬ 1H interval (00:21:25 - 01:21:25)
3    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 00:23:25      7 ⎪
4    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 01:21:25     -- ⎭
5    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 02:21:25     --  
6    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 03:21:25     --
7    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 04:21:25     --

8    1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 15:21:25     -- ⎫
9    1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 15:21:30      3 ⎪
10   1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 15:22:25      6 ⎬ 1H interval (15:21:25 - 16:21:25)
11   1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 16:21:25     -- ⎭
12   1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 16:21:25      9
13   1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 17:21:25     --
14   1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 18:21:25     --
15   1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 18:21:25     10
16   1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 18:30:25     10
17   1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 19:21:25     --

18   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 08:11:20     -- ⎫
19   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 08:21:25      1 ⎬ 1H interval (08:11:20 - 09:11:20)
20   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 09:11:20     -- ⎭
21   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 09:11:20      2
22   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 09:21:25      3
23   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 10:11:20     --
24   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 10:12:12      4
25   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 10:30:00      5
26   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 11:11:20     --
27   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 11:50:48      6
28   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 11:59:15      7
29   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 12:11:20     --
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

**Update:**
Here is what I've done so far:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
groups = df.groupby('id')['init_time'].first()
for g in groups:
  tmp = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(g, periods=5, freq="H"))
  tmp['value'] = -1
  df2 = df2.append(tmp,ignore_index=False)
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=False)
df2['event_time'] = df2.pop('index')
```

The code creates the missing rows:

```
    value          event_time
0      -1 2020-10-21 00:21:25
1      -1 2020-10-21 01:21:25
2      -1 2020-10-21 02:21:25
3      -1 2020-10-21 03:21:25
4      -1 2020-10-21 04:21:25
5      -1 2020-10-21 15:21:25
6      -1 2020-10-21 16:21:25
7      -1 2020-10-21 17:21:25
8      -1 2020-10-21 18:21:25
9      -1 2020-10-21 19:21:25
10     -1 2020-10-21 08:11:20
11     -1 2020-10-21 09:11:20
12     -1 2020-10-21 10:11:20
13     -1 2020-10-21 11:11:20
14     -1 2020-10-21 12:11:20
```

Now I need to figure out how to merge the DFs, or maybe find a better alternative

**Update2:** I'm looking to optimize the solution given by @Serge Ballesta, to gain performance time.

Comment: Do you want to do this in real time or after the data has been collected?

Comment: After data is collected

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a clever way. So I only propose:

1. get a *row* of data per `id` with the `init_time` column (assumed to be unique for the id)
2. add a new `event_time` column built from a `date_range` and concatenate everything
3. concatenate that with the initial dataframe, sort and build a new index

Code could be (assuming the dataframe is `df` and the `xxx_time` columns have `datetime64[ns]` dtypes):

```
# extract init_time per id
df1 = df[['id', 'init_time']].drop_duplicates()

# build the new event_time data
df2 = pd.concat(pd.DataFrame({'id': [s[1]['id']] * 5,
                              'init_time': [s[1]['init_time']] * 5,
                              'event_time': pd.date_range(s[1]['init_time'],
                                                          periods=5,
                                                          freq='1H')})
                for s in df1.iterrows())

# concat with the initial dataframe
final = pd.concat((df, df2)).sort_values(['id', 'event_time']).reset_index(
    drop=True)
```

With you example data, it gives:

```
    id           init_time          event_time  value
0    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 00:21:25    NaN
1    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 00:21:30    1.0
2    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 00:21:35    3.0
3    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 00:23:25    7.0
4    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 01:21:25    NaN
5    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 02:21:25    NaN
6    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 03:21:25    NaN
7    0 2020-10-21 00:21:25 2020-10-21 04:21:25    NaN
8    1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 15:21:25    NaN
9    1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 15:21:30    3.0
10   1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 15:22:25    6.0
11   1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 16:21:25    9.0
12   1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 16:21:25    NaN
13   1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 17:21:25    NaN
14   1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 18:21:25   10.0
15   1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 18:21:25    NaN
16   1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 18:30:25   10.0
17   1 2020-10-21 15:21:25 2020-10-21 19:21:25    NaN
18   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 08:11:20    NaN
19   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 08:21:25    1.0
20   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 09:11:20    2.0
21   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 09:11:20    NaN
22   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 09:21:25    3.0
23   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 10:11:20    NaN
24   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 10:12:12    4.0
25   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 10:30:00    5.0
26   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 11:11:20    NaN
27   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 11:50:48    6.0
28   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 11:59:15    7.0
29   2 2020-10-21 08:11:20 2020-10-21 12:11:20    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks  for the reply, your code works, however, runtime is very long on my real dataset. How can we improve it?

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz: It is no surprise, the reason why I started my answer with *I could not find a clever way*. `iterrows` is known to lead to simple to implement solutions but with poor performances when size increases. `groupby` and `apply` could also be tried, but they are slightly more complex to setup and the gain should be benchmarked. With that sample data, there is no gain...

Comment: I don't have time to write up an answer right now, but I think that if instead of developing the timedeltas along the rows, you develop them into `periods` columns and then `melt` the dataframe, you can leverage array operations and avoid the iterrows. E.g. after you create `df1`, you add `5` new columns in which you add 1 hour to `init_time`, then turn such columns in new rows using something like `melt`, then you just have to clean up a bit, but should be faster.

Comment: @gionni: I was surprised with it, but with the sample data, `melt` seems to be slower that `iterrows` (not tested with more rows...)